# Android permissions for Lollipop

Tags: android

**Problem** is, even when I refuse to give permission for `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` in dialog, when I check permission in another activity of this app, it returns `PERMISSION_GRANTED`. It happens in android `5(Lollipop)`. Could you give some advice, why it's happening?

I check permission by this way:

```
int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Browser.this,
                            android.Manifest.permission .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

}else{

}
```

Comment: *refuse to give permission .. It happens in android 5* Huh? it doesn't make sens ... there is no runtime permissions on android 5 so `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` always would return that permission is granted

Comment: The dynamic permission are come into picture in marshmallow. if you are using lollipop then it will automatically grant your permission.

Comment: I think you are mixing ask for runtime permision dialog with some other dialog (like: asking user for enable gps)

Comment: @Selvin, yeah, you are right, it asks to enable gps , sorry

Comment: Runtime permission is from 6.0 and greater.. As you told that it is lollypop you must have provided it in manifest which is enough! and you will always get the permission

Comment: @Selvin, But there is one more weirdness, from the settings of app I can change permissions of app, the same thing goes here, if Lolipop always has granted permissions, how can I change permission from GRANTED to DENIED?

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if current sdk is below marshmallow

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {

int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(Browser.this,
                            android.Manifest.permission .ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
if (permissionCheck == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

}else{


      }
        } else {
            // permission alredy granted
        }
```

Comment: I don't believe this is necessary. It does not answer the question (the answer is simply: what the OP wants to do is not possible). On Android versions < Marshmallow, `ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission` returns permission based on only the declarations in the AndroidManifest and won't require runtime permissions. So it should be safe to do this without version check.